# Result of a SELECT into a new table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi does anyone know how to add the result of your SELECT in a new table?

```
SELECT Postcode, Punten1, Punten2, Punten3, Punten4 FROM main_inboedel, ouderdom,
       levensfase, inkomen, oppervlakte
 WHERE main_inboedel.Ouderdomnummer = ouderdom.Ouderdomnummer
   AND main_inboedel.Levensfasenummer = levensfase.Levensfasenummer
   AND main_inboedel.Inkomennummer = inkomen.Inkomennummer
   AND main_inboedel.Oppervlaktenummer = oppervlakte.Oppervlaktenummer
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: That is not a DBMS, that is a frontend tool.

Comment: oh im sorry, it is mysql

Answer (score 9):

```
CREATE TABLE tablename AS SELECT field1,field2 FROM othertable;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
into NEWTABLE
from OLDTABLE
```

Comment: That seems to be non standard-SQL. Which DBMS supports this?

Comment: Not a trick question. That syntax does not comply with the SQL standard. I'm curious which DBMS supports this. That's all.

Comment: Its SQL Server, but you're right apparently this isnt standard SQL. Thanks for the info

Comment: Postgres SQL support this syntax